# How to suppress the confidence intervals on a ggplot cumulative incidence curves?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a [cumulative incidence curves for competing risks](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggcompetingrisks.html).

```
ggcompetingrisks (cmprsk_cuminc, # http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/survminer/reference/ggcompetingrisks.html
                                 conf.int = TRUE,
                                 xlab = "Time in years",
                                 ylab = "Cumulative Incidence",
                                 xlim = c(0, 5),
                                 break.time.by = 10,
                                 fontsize = 5,
                                 #ggtheme = theme_bw(),
                                 font.main = 18,
                                 font.x =  16,
                                 font.y = 16,
                                 font.tickslab = 12,
                                 palette = c("green", "blue", "red"))
```

[image: Cumulative Incidence Curves for Competing Risks]

However, when I want to remove the confidence intervals of the curves with the command

```
...conf.int = FALSE,...
```

I get the following message of error:

```
Error in ggcompetingrisks(cmprsk_cuminc_gender, conf.int = TRUE, xlab = "Time in years",  : 
  formal argument "conf.int" matched by multiple actual arguments.
```

Any idea of how to suppress the confidences intervals?

Thanks you

Comment: The message seems to suggest you have written both `conf.int =TRUE` and `conf.int = FALSE`?

Comment: Oops! Indeed you are right! I did not spot this gross mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The error came from the option conf.int was written two times at two separate unnoticed places. The following works fine.

```
ggcompetingrisks (cmprsk_cuminc_gender, xlab = "Time in years", 
                                        ylab = "Cumulative Incidence",
                                        xlim = c(0, 5),
                                        break.time.by = 10,
                                        fontsize = 5,
                                        #ggtheme = theme_bw(),
                                        font.main = 18,
                                        font.x =  16,
                                        font.y = 16,
                                        font.tickslab = 12,
                                        palette = c("green", "blue", "red"),
                                        multiple_panels = FALSE,
                                        conf.int = FALSE)
```

[Cumulative Incidence Curves for Competing Risks without confidence intervalls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4qSh.jpg)

Lesson learned: always check your code thoroughly.